# How to get good performance with reqwest

Tags: performance, rust, reqwest

I'm getting much worst performance than what I expect when running some simple requests with the `reqwest` crate. I wrote a simple program just to demonstrate that:

```rust
use tokio::time::Instant;

const URL: &str = "http://localhost:3000/health";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    {
        let now = Instant::now();
        reqwest::get(URL).await.unwrap();
        println!("reqwest: {:.3?}", now.elapsed());
    }
    {
        let now = Instant::now();
        ureq::get(URL).call().unwrap();
        println!("ureq: {:.3?}", now.elapsed());
    }
}
```

When running it I get:

```bash
$ cargo run --bin perf --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.08s
     Running `target/release/perf`
reqwest: 33.126ms
ureq: 543.672µs
```

That's a 60x difference. I've done a bit more testing with concurrent and parallel queries ([some of those experiments can be seen here](https://github.com/glehmann/reqwest_perf)) and it even gets worth when increasing the parallelism.

How do I get better query performance with `reqwest`?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume that the issue is with reqwest just from this code. For example, if I reverse the order of the two blocks you have here (i.e. run `ureq` first) then `reqwest` is faster. Also `reqest::get` initializes a new `Client` on each call, which isn't how you would normally use it when performance is an issue. `ureq` may do the same, but again, this isn't a realistic test of making requests with either of them in a real app. It might be useful to try running each with a profiler and see where the time is actually spent. I'd guess a lot is in initalization.

Comment: @ShauntheSheep this is a very simple example on purpose in order to focus on the question of how to use reqwest to get good performance, and not on how to measure performance. I also tried to run ureq and reqwest in the reverse order and to run a non measured query for each lib before doing the actual measurement.

Comment: the test is quite realistic in my case: this is done in a cli tool that runs 2 or 3 consecutive queries. The tool itself may be used in loop in a shell script were the execution time would have a significant impact. And indeed in that cli tool I do initialize a single client that I reuse, but still get some quite poor performance…

Comment: This is a flawed test. Run both *at least twice*. You could be measuring the DNS latency. I'd try running at least 10 cycles with one of each.

Comment: as said in a previous comment, I did run the queries twice for each lib — just haven't included it in the question for simplicity

Comment: @ShauntheSheep advice to run in a profiler was indeed a good advice: running it in samply shows that `reqwest::get` is spending most of its time in `openssl::ssl::connector::SslConnector::builder`. Disabling reqwest's default features (and thus native-tls support) gives performance much closer to ureq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiling the program execution with [samply](https://github.com/mstange/samply) showed that reqwest is spending most of its time in `openssl::ssl::connector::SslConnector::builder` on the test machine running Ubuntu 23.10.

`reqwest` supports many [optional features](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/#optional-features) that may have an impact of the performances. In that cas, using the `rustls-tls` feature of the default `native-tls` drastically reduce the reqwest's client creation time.

In `Cargo.toml`, `native-tls` may be disabled by specifying `default-features = false` on the `reqwest` dependency:

```ini
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11.23", default-features = false, features = ["rustls-tls"] }
```

With only that change, the same test program now produces much closer performance between `reqwest` and `ureq`:

```bash
$ cargo run --bin perf --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.08s
     Running `target/release/perf`
reqwest: 539.808µs
ureq: 208.114µs
```

The results are now quite close and shouldn't be read as anything significant: no effort was done to be statistically relevant.